# Movie where aliens ally themselves with humans and win war with human technology

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

My friend, who doesn't know English, is trying to find a movie.

An alien species is in a war, and has allied itself with humanity.
The aliens supplied the humans with spaceships, but they used human technology on land combats.

The technology from the humans was so primitive compared with the bad guys' that it ends up giving the aliens an advantage in the war.

The enemy aliens' shields were made to repel lasers and photon cannons, not bullets. They were also unable to track the humans' radio waves and the heat from diesel engines.

The good aliens win the war due to this.

It seemed to be an American production and it's not *Aliens*.

Update: My friend has just remembered it was most likely from the 80's.

Comment: Was it live action? I'm assuming so since you haven't mentioned otherwise.

Comment: Anything familiar here? http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RockBeatsLaser

Answer (score 3):

That brings to mind the [Stargate SG-1](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118480/) episode [Small Victories](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0709173/), (2000).  [Here is a clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dGiSNPYj_iU) of the Asgard explaining that "You have demonstrated their weakness may be found through a less... sophisticated approach. We are no longer capable of such thinking."

Later in the episode he refers to human firearms: "The Asgard would never invent a weapon that propels small weights of iron and carbon alloys, by igniting a powder of potassium nitrate, charcoal and sulfur."

Comment: It's very similar, but the movie I'm looking for was from before 2000.